# Como evitar que se ingresen ciertos caracteres en un campo

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Estoy con un formulario, en donde se tiene que ingresar un lugar de un evento. Se me ocurrió poner en lugar de la palabra "Barrio" Los caracteres "B°" y el proceso de grabación me arrojó error.

```
$lugar = htmlentities(addslashes($_POST['lugar']));
```

así "limpio" y controlo lo que se ingresa en ese campo. 
Utilizo PDO para realizar la grabación de los datos en MySQL

```
$stmt->bindValue(":lugar", $lugar);
```

Así proceso la información del campo en cuestión 
Que puede estar pasando ?

Comment: Me pregunto lo mismo, _¿qué puede estar pasando?_, **¿cuál es el error que te está arrojando?**. La pregunta no es del todo clara. Si usas PDO, te puedes olvidar de usar `addslashes`, es un mito que te protejan de algo. Sugiero que, si tienes tiempo, [leas esta larga respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/53280/29967) en la que se trata el tema, en el punto 4 sobre todo. Usar PDO adecuadamente es suficiente.

Comment: Asegúrate de que PDO no utiliza sentencias preparadas emuladas, `$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);` . Asegúrate de utilizar una codificación de caracteres que pueda representar lo que necesitas, se recomienda utf8 y en bases de datos MySQL utf8mb4. Edita tu pregunta y pon que error te da, para que podamos entender que esta pasando. @MNibor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

este código puede servirte para normalizar la cadena:

```
function sanear_string($string)
{

$string = trim($string);

$string = str_replace(
    array('á', 'à', 'ä', 'â', 'ª', 'Á', 'À', 'Â', 'Ä'),
    array('a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A'),
    $string
);

$string = str_replace(
    array('é', 'è', 'ë', 'ê', 'É', 'È', 'Ê', 'Ë'),
    array('e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E'),
    $string
);

$string = str_replace(
    array('í', 'ì', 'ï', 'î', 'Í', 'Ì', 'Ï', 'Î'),
    array('i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'I'),
    $string
);

$string = str_replace(
    array('ó', 'ò', 'ö', 'ô', 'Ó', 'Ò', 'Ö', 'Ô'),
    array('o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'),
    $string
);

$string = str_replace(
    array('ú', 'ù', 'ü', 'û', 'Ú', 'Ù', 'Û', 'Ü'),
    array('u', 'u', 'u', 'u', 'U', 'U', 'U', 'U'),
    $string
);

$string = str_replace(
    array('ñ', 'Ñ', 'ç', 'Ç'),
    array('n', 'N', 'c', 'C',),
    $string
);

$string = str_replace(
    array('¨', 'º', '-', '~',
         '#', '@', '|', '!', '"',
         '·', '$', "%", "&", "/",
         "(", ")", "?", "'", "¡",
         "¿", "[", "^", "<code>", "]",
         "+", "}", "{", "¨", "´",".",
         ">", "< ", ";", ",", ":"),
    '',
    $string
);
return $string;
}
```

Cortesía de: http://ecapy.com/reemplazar-la-n-acentos-espacios-y-caracteres-especiales-con-php-actualizada/index.html

Igualmente PHP ya tiene métodos por defectos:

http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

http://php.net/manual/es/pdo.quote.php